# Where is the x265 plugin for Intel Media SDK?

Tags: libx265

Envrionment: Windows 10. Intel Media SDK 2016.0.2

I have been using the Media SDK for decoding H.264 video. It works great. Now, I need to decode H.265 video. This seems to be just one line change in the source code. However, when run, I get the following error:

```
plugin_loader.h :166 [ERROR] Failed to load plugin from GUID,
sts=-9: { 0x15, 0xdd, 0x93, 0x68, 0x25, 0xad, 0x47, 0x5e, 0xa3, 0x4e, 0x35, 0xf3, 0xf5, 0x42, 0x17, 0xa6 }
(Intel (R) Media SDK plugin for HEVC DECODE)
Default plugin cannot be loaded (possibly you have to define plugin explicitly)
```

Strange. The same code works great for H.264 but seems to require a plugin for H.265. Is there something I am missing? Does anyone know where I can find this plugin? Regards.

Answer (score 1):

You pass the wrong GUID. For HEVC plugin for decoding you must use
mfxPluginUID  MFX_PLUGINID_HEVCD_HW     = {{0x33, 0xa6, 0x1c, 0x0b, 0x4c, 0x27, 0x45, 0x4c, 0xa8, 0xd8, 0x5d, 0xde, 0x75, 0x7c, 0x6f, 0x8e}};
(define in mfxplugin.h in Media SDK include folder)